# Regex to find numbers that are not in a phrase

Tags: python-3.x, regex

If I have e.g. this string:

```
Beschreibung Menge VK-Preis MwSt% Betrag
Schadenbewertunginkl.Restwertermittlung 1 25,00€ 19 25,00€
Rechnungsbetragexcl.MwSt.: 25,00€
MwSt.(19%): 4,75€
Rechnungsbetragincl.MwSt.: 123.029,75€
```

I want to extract all the numbers.
My regexes are:

```
regex_up_to_thousand = r'\b(?:\d{1,3}){1}(?:,{1}\d{2})\b'
```

and

```
regex_every_price = r'\b(?:\d{1,3}(\.|,))+(:?\d{3}(\.|,))(?:\d{2})\b'
```

My idea was to first get the "big" prices, remove them from the text and get the other numbers.
Which works in most cases, until I have a date that looks like this maybe

```
Gutachtennummer: 1009126 Leistungsdatum: 11.10.2021
```

I would get the 11.10 with my second regex, and I don't know how to prevent this.
I thought the `\b` would help, but sadly not.

Any ideas?
It's not the end of the world, since I do a lot of math in the background, but it's a possibility that a date would fit some values and I calculate something wrong in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following pattern.

```
\b\d+(?:(?:\.|,)\d{3})*(?:(?:\.|,)\d{2})\b(?!\W\d)
```

The main thing is `(?!\W\d)` at the end which ensures that after your amount you will not have a construct of 1 non-word character followed by 1 digit.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/q1ic9S/1

Comment: Oh well, that's nice, thank you very much. The only thing that needs to change is the d+ which should be a {1,3}, since those numbers allways appear in 3er groups ;D